# Adding HTTPS image URL in ArcGIS Explorer programmatically

Tags: imagery, sdk, arcgis-explorer

I have .jp2 and .tif satellite images hosted in my IIS web server. I am trying to access those imagery in  ArcGIS Explorer programmatically through VB.Net (without actually downloading the image in my machine where explorer application is running). I have tried `OpenRasterFile` method to pass https URL. However, this method is not accepting an HTTPS URL as an argument.

Is there any other way to  access imagery through HTTPS URL in ArcGIS Explorer?